# How to notify the user if OpenActivity related list is blank of Opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, process-builder, tasks, email-alert, activities

I am not sure about Process builder will work for this scenario or not but can anybody please tell me How to Notify the User If `OpenActivity` related list is blank of the Particular Opportunity `(Opportunity.OpenActivities == Null) ?` (Related list of OpenActivity is totally blank in Opportunity detail page)

I tried to create Process builder with Using Opportunity object & Task Object but i could not find the way to achieve this (In Task Process builder i used `Related To` as in my criteria).

**I have Professional Edition and i do not have permission to create Apex trigger or Workflow Rule for the same.**

Comment: What should Trigger notifying the User `OpenActivity` is blank?

Comment: it should notify the user that this Opportunity does not have any open Activity so, assign task to it. hope this is clear now !!

Comment: I understand that, but you need something to Trigger that check so it can assign tasks, send e-mails etc... Typically this might be a time-based criteria in a Workflow, for example, or a Batch Class scheduled to run every few ours that looks for empty `OpenActivity` against `Opportunity`.

Comment: @DanJones i understand the way you are talking about but i really don't understand what criteria i should write up to check that yes this Opportunity don't have any open Activity

Comment: That's something you'll really need to think about then. Finding empty one's isn't particularly difficult as illustrated by @AdrianLarson's answer below, but you need to consider exactly what should Trigger the actions.

Comment: i thought that let's use formula field on Opportunity to count total number of activities available in the related list and if count is 0 then notify the user but it is only possible with the Apex Trigger and i don't have permission to create it :) anyways thanks @DanJones

Comment: You could do something like that, but again something would need to Trigger to read the value of the Formula Field. For instance, when a record is created, updated or deleted, or during a Time-Based Criterea (e.g. if after 3 days `Formula__c` == 0, do something).

Comment: Okay !! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get a *rough approximation* using the `LastActivityDate` field. If it is `null`, you know for sure there are no open activities, because there are none of any variety. If it is in the future, you know there are open activities. If it is in the past, there is some ambiguity, as you can have open tasks which are past due. Still, these criteria might work well enough for your needs:

```
OR(ISNULL(LastActivityDate), LastActivityDate < TODAY())
```

Comment: i tried the above formula and it's working only when i am going to create a opportunity, when i update the existing opportunity with No OpenActivities then process builder is not firing and did not get the expected output...`OR(ISNULL(LastActivityDate), LastActivityDate < DATEVALUE(NOW()))`